# How to write multiple items in dynamo db using s3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

So I'm trying to insert multiple items in a dynamodb table. I'm reading my data from a csv file and everything's going write(My logs in aws cloudwatch shows me that I'm correctly extracting my data from the csv file).
I've first try in a loop to write each element in the table like this:

```
for item in Items:
  response = dynamodb.put_item(
        TableName = 'some_table_name',
        Item = item)
```

For this syntax I'm using the dynamodb client like this:
`dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name=region)`
After this attempt, I've tried to used to batch write in a loop like this:

```
for item in Items:
  response = dynamodb.batch_write_item(
    RequestItems={
        'some_table': [
                 {
                        'PutRequest': {
                            'Item':item
                         }
                 }
          ]
     }
   )
   print('Successfully uploaded to DynamoDB')
```

And I'm still using the dynamodb client.
After those two attempts, I've tried the same functions with the dynamodb resource (`dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name=region)`).
The problem is that my list `Items` has 42 items, and all those tentatives put different number of items (25,27,29) but never 42. So where am I doing wrong? Can u guys help me please?

Comment: What do the items look like and what is your key schema? Are you sure, you're not just overwriting some items a couple of times because the keys are identical?

Comment: You might want to try setting `ReturnValues="ALL_OLD"` and then printing the response to see if something is being overwritten due to identical keys.

Answer (score -2):

Try implementing retry mechanism for your bachwrite

```
result, batchError := svc.DynamoDBBatchWrite(input)

if result != nil && len(result.UnprocessedItems) > 0 {
                input = &dynamodb.BatchWriteItemInput{
                    RequestItems: result.UnprocessedItems,
                }
            }
```

and then retry till the result.UnprocessedItems == 0

Comment: This looks like Go code in response to a question tagged with Python and including an example of Python. If this were the issue, I believe `boto3` would have raised an exception.

Comment: Yeah I guess the logic should hold true. Due to bandwidth restriction we have to retry till all records are successfully persisted. Did anything worked?

Comment: @Brice in case you are unaware - [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)